# ccze very slow to colour logs

Tags: performance, colors

I want to use [`ccze`](http://freecode.com/projects/ccze) to colourize my logs, but it's too slow:

Operating on 1832 lines of logs:

```
$ journalctl --since 12:00 --until 12:30 | wc -l
1832
```

Without colouring, getting the logs takes 0.01s in user time:

```
$ time journalctl --since 12:00 --until 12:30 > /dev/null

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.007s
```

With `ccze`, it takes 32.66 seconds (3260x longer!):

```
$ time journalctl --since 12:00 --until 12:30 | ccze > /dev/null

real    0m40.965s
user    0m32.660s
sys     0m2.193s
```

In comparison, [`grc`](https://github.com/garabik/grc) only takes 0.24s (24x as long):

```
$ time grc journalctl --since 12:00 --until 12:30 > /dev/null                                                                                              24.3s | 24 Aug 13:04

real    0m0.230s
user    0m0.237s
sys     0m0.017s
```

AFAIK I'm using the default configuration with `ccze 0.2.1`.

If it's this slow, it's probably only useful for following new writes to end of log files, eg with `journalctl -f`.

Is `ccze` usually this slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `-o nolookups` argument.  See the [man page for details](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ccze).

**18 seconds** with no arguments:

```
time journalctl --since 12:00 --until 12:10 | ccze > /dev/null
journalctl --since 12:00 --until 12:10  0.01s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 10.686 total
ccze > /dev/null  12.51s user 1.27s system 76% cpu 18.041 total
```

**0.15 seconds** with `-o nolookups`:

```
time journalctl --since 12:00 --until 12:10 | ccze -o nolookups > /dev/null
journalctl --since 12:00 --until 12:10  0.01s user 0.01s system 24% cpu 0.091 total
ccze -o nolookups > /dev/null  0.13s user 0.01s system 95% cpu 0.145 total
```

Comment: I've found `-A` useful to pipe to `less -FRX`.